# Using itemize inside of equations

Tags: latex

I want to use an item list inside of an equation, so the whole list only gets referenced as a whole equation.

If I just use itemize and put my equations in each of the items I will get a reference for each of the equations instead of all of them. Think of it as you wanted to write down some properties of some function and want to reference the properties in general.

The following examples are not working like they should:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[(i)] $Bla$
\item[(ii)] $Bla bla$
\item[(iii)] $Bla bla bla$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Theres just no reference at all.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}

\begin{itemize}
\item equation1
\item euqation2
\end{itemize}

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This just gives an error, because itemize is used inside an equation.

Hope someone can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225100 you could something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcounter{mysubequations}

\renewcommand{\themysubequations}{(\roman{mysubequations})}

\newcommand{\mysubnumber}{\refstepcounter{mysubequations}\themysubequations}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}\setcounter{mysubequations}{0}
      \mysubnumber\quad &equation1\\
      \mysubnumber\quad &equation2\\
      \mysubnumber\quad &equation3\\
    \end{aligned}
    \label{key}
\end{equation}


\ref{key}

\end{document}
```

[image]